# Creating a Windows application which reads and writes excel spreadsheets + reads and writes emails

Tags: vba, vbscript, excel

I'm an intern in Europe working at a hospital. My daily job is to find replacements for a nurse or doctor or surgeon when one is needed. To do this, I receive a request from a certain department, in the form of an excel spreadsheet with 4 different attributes which determines the time, department and specific type of personnel required.

From that info I look into a fixed database which is also based in an excel spreadsheet, for someone who matches the requirements.

After I send an email/sms or call the department head to get an approval, in which the reply is almost always yes.

Once I get the confirmation, I send the replacement's information to the department which requires the replacement and then my job is done. I do about 150 of these requests a day and if I can write a program for this, I would be able to save the hospital a lot of tax payers money, as they employ 3 other people to do this job.

Therefore, my question:
**What is the best language to write this program in?**

Would you recommend a scripting language which may make it easier to access files and send emails? or would that we too weak for this task?

**The requirements for the language are to do the following:**

- **Access excel spreadsheets**
- **Read the spreadsheet and copy the values from an array of cells**
- **Find a value in the spreadsheet**
- **send emails with the values I obtained in my excel spreadsheet search?**
- **read an email and if value is = to YES, do ... else do ...**
- **finally, send an email with xxxxx information to xxx person**

*If I were using my mac, I would have gone to a scripting language like applescript combined with automator to access and read the excel files and send emails/sms's.*

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: What languages do you know and can write idiomatic code in?

Comment: You can use VBA in excel for all those things except "read an email", for which it will depend on your mail system. If you use Outlook, you can use VBA there too.

Comment: I am an intermediate C and C++ programmer and I've created several small scripts using applescript and such. HTML and Javascript are my strongest suit though.

Comment: Would I be able to incorporate a VBA macro in excel into another language. Eg, could I write an application in C++ which gives the VBA macro a spreadsheet to read, and then obtains a value from the macro and saves it, then to use it in something else?

Comment: @TonyDallimore to answer your questions:
- I only receive one 1 workbook per request (so 150workbooks/day)
- I do receive the workbooks through Outlook
- the check is rather complicated, although if all requirements are met, it is easy. If not I have to go into four other databases (which are external)
- The email reply is to the same person who sends the request.
- And all emails are done through Outlook.

I'm sensing that everything could be done through VBA, and in the chance that no one is found in the database, the task can be done manually.

Comment: Let us assume the solution is going to be coded in VBA.  We can review this assumption later but before that I need you to rewrite your question to provide a specification; your question is too vague at the moment.  First can we automate receipt of an email?  Are they addressed to a particular inbox? Do they have a particular header?  Does the attached workbook have a particular style of name?  It would be good to have a routine that every five minutes, say, looks for appropriate emails and saves the attached workbook ready for the next stage.

Comment: Next what information is in a workbook?  Is it in a worksheet with a particular name?  If you can provide this information, I can get you started.  By the way, to save cluttering Stack Overflow, I will delete obsolete comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is a long way from a complete solution.  Its purpose is to start you thinking about how your system will function.

Looking to the future, I envisage the need for a text file which I have named *HumanActionRequired.txt*.  The tenth line of code is a constant that specifies the folder in which this file will be created.  You must replace "C:\DataArea\Play" with the name of a folder on your system.  You may wish to rename the file: see sixth line.

Although I envisage this file to be the destination of error messages, I have used it here to list details of the messages in InBox.  I have only output a small selection of the available properties but it should get you thinking about what is possible.

The code below belongs in a Module within OutLook:

1. Open Outlook.
2. Select Tools, Macro and Security.  You will need to set the security level to Medium.  Later you can discuss getting trusted status for your macro with your IT department but this will do for now.
3. Select Tools, Macro and Visual Basic Editor or click Alt+F11.
4. You will probably see the Project Explorer down the left (Control+R to display if not).  If you have never created an Outlook macro, the area to the right will be grey.
5. Select Insert, Module.  The grey area will go white with the code area above and the Immediate window below.
6. Copy the code below into the code area.

Position the cursor within the macro *LocateInterestingEmails()* and click F5.  You will be warned that a macro is trying to access your emails.  Tick *Allow access for* and select a time limit then click Yes.  The macro will write selected properties of the emails in Inbox to the file *HumanActionRequired.txt*.

```
Option Explicit
Sub LocateInterestingEmails()

  Dim ErrorDescription As String
  Dim ErrorNumber As Long
  Static ErrorCount As Integer
  Const FileCrnt As String = "HumanActionRequired.txt"
  Dim FolderTgt As MAPIFolder
  Dim InxAttachCrnt As Long
  Dim InxItemCrnt As Long
  Dim OutputFileNum As Long
  Const PathCrnt As String = "C:\DataArea\Play"

  ErrorCount = 0
  OutputFileNum = 0

Restart:

  ' On Error GoTo CloseDown

  Set FolderTgt = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). _
              GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

  OutputFileNum = FreeFile
  Open PathCrnt & "\" & FileCrnt For Append Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

  For InxItemCrnt = 1 To FolderTgt.Items.Count
    With FolderTgt.Items.Item(InxItemCrnt)

      If .Class = olMail Then
        Print #OutputFileNum, "-----------------------------"
        Print #OutputFileNum, "Subject: " & .Subject
        Print #OutputFileNum, "Sender: " & .SenderEmailAddress
        Print #OutputFileNum, "Recipient: " & .To
        Print #OutputFileNum, "Date sent: " & .SentOn
        If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
          Print #OutputFileNum, "Attachments:"
          For InxAttachCrnt = 1 To .Attachments.Count
            Print #OutputFileNum, "  " & .Attachments(InxAttachCrnt).DisplayName
          Next
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next

CloseDown:
  ErrorNumber = Err.Number
  ErrorDescription = Err.Description
  Err.Clear

  Set FolderTgt = Nothing

  If ErrorNumber <> 0 Then
    ' Here because of an error
    If OutputFileNum = 0 Then
      ' Output file not open
      OutputFileNum = FreeFile
      Open PathCrnt & "\" & FileCrnt For Append Lock Write As #OutputFileNum
    End If
    Print #OutputFileNum, "-----------------------------"
    Print #OutputFileNum, "Error at " & Now()
    Print #OutputFileNum, "Error number = " & ErrorNumber & _
                          "   description = " & ErrorDescription
  End If

  If OutputFileNum <> 0 Then
    ' File open
    Close OutputFileNum
    OutputFileNum = 0
  End If

End Sub
```

**Version 2**

This version includes the code in the first version plus:

- It opens an existing workbook to which it saves information about the Excel attachments found.
- It identifies attachments with an extension of `xls?` and saves them to disc with a name based on the date/time received and the sender's name.
- It opens each saved attachment.  For each worksheet in a saved attachment, it creates a row in the existing workbook containing filenames, sender name and email address, sheet name and the value of cell A1.

I do not think this code will be directly useful but it shows how to save attachments and open workbooks to read from or write to then which I believe you will need.

The only code I know to be missing is:

- Move processed email to save folder.
- Generate reply email.

However, more code may be necessary depending on how you want to automate the entire process.

The code below is not as neat as I would like.  I do not want to add any more until you have fully understood it.  I would also like a better understanding of the emails you plan to send and the desired automation of the total process.

Come back with questions on any part of the code you do not understand.

```
Option Explicit
Sub LocateInterestingEmails()

  ' I use constants to indentify columns in worksbooks because if I move the
  ' column I only need to update the constant to update the code.  I said the
  ' same in a previous answer and some one responded that they preferred
  ' Enumerations.  I use Enumerations a lot but I still prefer to use constants
  ' for column numbers.
  Const ColSumFileNameSaved As String = "A"
  Const ColSumFileNameOriginal As String = "B"
  Const ColSumSenderName As String = "C"
  Const ColSumSenderEmail As String = "D"
  Const ColSumSheet As String = "E"
  Const ColSumCellA1 As String = "F"

  ' You must change the value of this constant to the name of a folder on your
  ' computer.  All file created by this macro are written to this folder.
  Const PathCrnt As String = "C:\DataArea\Play"

  ' I suggest you change the values of these constants to
  ' something that you find helpful.
  Const FileNameHAR As String = "HumanActionRequired.txt"
  Const FileNameSummary As String = "Paolo.xls"

  Dim CellValueA1 As Variant
  Dim ErrorDescription As String
  Dim ErrorNumber As Long
  Dim FileNameReqDisplay As String
  Dim FileNameReqSaved As String
  Dim FolderTgt As MAPIFolder
  Dim InxAttachCrnt As Long
  Dim InxItemCrnt As Long
  Dim InxSheet As Long
  Dim OutputFileNum As Long
  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim ReceivedTime As Date
  Dim RowSummary As Long
  Dim SenderName As String
  Dim SenderEmail As String
  Dim SheetName As String
  Dim XlApp As Excel.Application
  Dim XlWkBkRequest As Excel.Workbook
  Dim XlWkBkSummary As Excel.Workbook

  ' Ensure resource controls are null before macro does anything that can cause
  ' an error so error handler knows if the resource is to be released.
  OutputFileNum = 0
  Set XlApp = Nothing
  Set XlWkBkRequest = Nothing
  Set XlWkBkSummary = Nothing

  ' Open own copy of Excel
  Set XlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  With XlApp
    .Visible = True         ' This slows your macro but helps during debugging
    ' Open workbook to which a summary of workbooks extracted will be written
    Set XlWkBkSummary = .Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & "\" & FileNameSummary)
    With XlWkBkSummary.Worksheets("Summary")
      ' Set RowSummary to one more than the last currently used row
      RowSummary = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColSumFileNameSaved).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
  End With

Restart:

  ' I prefer to have my error handler switched off during development so the
  ' macro stops on the faulty statement.  If you remove the comment mark from
  ' the On Error statement then any error will cause the code to junp to label
  ' CloseDown which is at the bottom of this routine.

  ' On Error GoTo CloseDown

  ' Gain access to InBox
  Set FolderTgt = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). _
              GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

  ' Open text file for output.  I envisage this file being used for error
  ' messages but for this version of the macro I write a summary of the
  ' contents of the InBox to it.
  OutputFileNum = FreeFile
  Open PathCrnt & "\" & FileNameHAR For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

For InxItemCrnt = 1 To FolderTgt.Items.Count
  With FolderTgt.Items.Item(InxItemCrnt)

    If .Class = olMail Then
      ' Only interested in mail items.  Most of the other items will be
      ' meeting requests.
      Print #OutputFileNum, "-----------------------------"
      Print #OutputFileNum, "Subject: " & .Subject
      ' Currently we are within With FolderTgt.Items.Item(InxItemCrnt).
      ' Values from this mail item are to be written to a workbook
      ' for which another With will be required.  Copy values to
      ' variables for they are accessable.
      ' Note: XlApp.XlWkBkSummary.Worksheets("Summary")
      '         .Cells(RowSummary, ColSumFileNameOriginal).Value = _
      '       FolderTgt.Items.Item(InxItemCrnt).Attachments(InxAttachCrnt) _
      '       .DisplayName
      ' is legal but is not very clear.  Code is much clearer will full use
      ' of With stateents even if it means values must be copied to variable.
      SenderName = .SenderName
      SenderEmail = .SenderEmailAddress
      ReceivedTime = .ReceivedTime
      Print #OutputFileNum, "SenderName: " & SenderName
      Print #OutputFileNum, "SenderAddr: " & SenderEmail
      Print #OutputFileNum, "Received: " & ReceivedTime
      Print #OutputFileNum, "Date sent: " & .SentOn
      If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        Print #OutputFileNum, "Attachments:"
        For InxAttachCrnt = 1 To .Attachments.Count
          With .Attachments(InxAttachCrnt)
            ' I cannot find an example for which the
            ' DisplayName and FileName are different
            FileNameReqDisplay = .DisplayName
            Print #OutputFileNum, "  " & FileNameReqDisplay & "|" & .FileName
            Pos = InStrRev(FileNameReqDisplay, ".")
            ' With ... End With and If ... End If must be properly nested.
            ' Within the If below I want access to the attachment and to the
            ' workbook.  Hence the need to terminate the current With and then
            ' immediately start it again within the If ... End If block.
          End With
          If LCase(Mid(FileNameReqDisplay, Pos + 1, 3)) = "xls" Then
            With .Attachments(InxAttachCrnt)
              ' Save the attachment with a unique name.  Note this will only be
              ' unique if you do not save the same attachment again.
              FileNameReqSaved = _
                   Format(ReceivedTime, "yyyymmddhhmmss") & " " & SenderName
              .SaveAsFile PathCrnt & "\" & FileNameReqSaved
            End With
            ' Open the saved attachment
            Set XlWkBkRequest = _
                         XlApp.Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & "\" & FileNameReqSaved)
            With XlWkBkRequest
              'Examine every worksheet in workbook
              For InxSheet = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
                With .Worksheets(InxSheet)
                  ' Save sheet name and a sample value
                  SheetName = .Name
                  CellValueA1 = .Cells(1, 1).Value
                End With
                ' Save information about this sheet and its workbook
                With XlWkBkSummary.Worksheets("Summary")
                  .Cells(RowSummary, ColSumFileNameSaved).Value = _
                                                            FileNameReqSaved
                  .Cells(RowSummary, ColSumFileNameOriginal).Value = _
                                                          FileNameReqDisplay
                  .Cells(RowSummary, ColSumSenderName).Value = SenderName
                  .Cells(RowSummary, ColSumSenderEmail).Value = SenderEmail
                  .Cells(RowSummary, ColSumSheet).Value = SheetName
                  .Cells(RowSummary, ColSumCellA1).Value = CellValueA1
                  RowSummary = RowSummary + 1
                End With  ' XlWkBkSummary.Worksheets("Summary")
              Next InxSheet
              .Close SaveChanges:=False
              Set XlWkBkRequest = Nothing
            End With  ' XlWkBkRequest
          End If
        Next
      End If
    End If
  End With
Next

CloseDown:
ErrorNumber = Err.Number
ErrorDescription = Err.Description
Err.Clear

Set FolderTgt = Nothing

If ErrorNumber <> 0 Then
  ' Have reached here because of an error
  If OutputFileNum = 0 Then
    ' Output file not open
    OutputFileNum = FreeFile
    Open PathCrnt & "\" & FileNameHAR For Append Lock Write As #OutputFileNum
  End If
  Print #OutputFileNum, "-----------------------------"
  Print #OutputFileNum, "Error at " & Now()
  Print #OutputFileNum, "Error number = " & ErrorNumber & _
                        "   description = " & ErrorDescription
End If

' Release resources

If OutputFileNum <> 0 Then
  ' File open
  Close OutputFileNum
  OutputFileNum = 0
End If

If Not (XlWkBkRequest Is Nothing) Then
  XlWkBkRequest.Close SaveChanges:=False
  Set XlWkBkRequest = Nothing
End If

If Not (XlWkBkSummary Is Nothing) Then
  XlWkBkSummary.Close SaveChanges:=True
  Set XlWkBkSummary = Nothing
End If

If Not (XlApp Is Nothing) Then
  XlApp.Quit
  Set XlApp = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is a great start. I am not able to work on this program till next week because I will be on holiday, but when I get back I will keep you updated on my progess. 

I suppose the first step is to download the attachment from the email request, and then download the replacement criteria, in order to proceed to the next step of search and find.

Comment: I doubt you will read this until you have returned from your holiday.  Hope you had a nice time.  Yes, the next step would be to save the required attachments.  I have added a new section to my answer to include access to Excel to show how it is done.

Comment: Hi Tony, I just got back from my holidays. I'm happy to say I worked on the program a bit, in the planning stages and not the coding stages however. Here is a pdf view of my mind map for the program. It's just the start however, with many more steps to come. here is the link to the pdf document for my program map: [CHUV mind map.pdf](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwA6KMKwkkySMWtWRFhsUV9xem8/edit)

Comment: I have been looking at the Mind map. Does "Erik: ....." mean you are waiting for a reply from Erik? The text on the extreme right implies you expect to be able to read information from a form. Forms are transient. Any selections made by the user must be saved in a cell or elsewhere. If you look at my profile you will see I keep an email address for Stack Overflow. I believe it would be easier to ask and answer questions via email than in 500-character comments.